# Accessing and Displaying Data from the Datastore

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I'm saving data to the datastore using:

```
    Entity pageText = new Entity("pageText");

    DatastoreService datastore =
            DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
    datastore.put(pageText);
```

But I'm unsure as of how to access and display that data from another servlet. Can anyone help out with this? Am I even saving this correctly?

Here is the full code for this servlet, just in case you want to take a look. Thank you!

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreService;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceFactory;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Entity;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class SaveServlet extends HttpServlet
{
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException
    {

        String pageOwner = (String) req.getAttribute("pageOwner");
        String pageName = (String) req.getAttribute("pageName");

        //String pageText = req.getParameter("pageText");

        Entity pageText = new Entity("pageText");

        DatastoreService datastore =
                DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
        datastore.put(pageText);

        Logger.getLogger("bleepbloop").warning("pageText = " + pageText);

        // Save the pageText into the datastore.

        resp.sendRedirect("/wiki/" + pageOwner + "/" + pageName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> But I'm unsure as of how to access and display that data from another
>   servlet.

So let's assume you have two App Engine apps deployed, app `A` and `B`. Now if I understand your question correctly, you would like to access app `A`'s datastore from *within* app `B`? If this is the case, I'm afraid you cannot do this *natively*.

As you see in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/811166/1101070) similar question, each app has its own datastore which cannot *natively* be shared among other (separate) App Engine apps.

Now having said that, one way of *sharing* data between separate servlets would be to build an API on top of the datastore. So in your case, servlet `A` could expose getter and setter functions via a [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) interface and servlet `B` could do whatever it needs to do with the data.

Note that in this scenario, servlet `B` does not necessarily have to be hosted on App Engine since all "datastore" calls now become simple HTTP calls.

**P.S.** If I've completely misunderstood your question and all you were actually asking was *how* to retrieve something from the datastore, [here's one example](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queries.html#Overview):

```
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreService;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceFactory;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Entity;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.PreparedQuery;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Query;

// ...
// Get the Datastore Service
DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();

// The Query interface assembles a query
Query q = new Query("pageText");

// PreparedQuery contains the methods for fetching query results
// from the datastore
PreparedQuery pq = datastore.prepare(q);

for (Entity result : pq.asIterable()) {
  String pageOwner = (String) result.getProperty("pageOwner");
  String pageName = (String) result.getProperty("pageName");
  System.out.println("Page " +pageName+ "'s owner is " +pageOwner);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code should work

```
DatastoreService service = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();  
Query q = new Query("pageText"); 
PreparedQuery pq = service.prepare(q);
PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
for (Entity result : pq.asIterable())
{ 
            out.println(result.getProperty("pageOwner") + " " + result.getProperty("pageName"));  
}
```

I hope it helps
/Dick Larsson