# Google App Engine App interoperability

Tags: google-app-engine

I have tried searching the info regarding applications on GAE within same domain talking to each other but so far I don't have any luck.  There was a post here but I don't know if that answer is correct.

Comment: Could you give some details on what you are trying out?

Comment: I am building two applications on GAE and two apps serve different business contexts but one may retrieve data from another app.  e.g. Client App retrieves Invoices from Invoice App.

Comment: This is a duplicated of question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/811166/google-app-engine-one-datastore-for-different-domains-and-apps. See the second answer, you can share the datastore across different versions of the same app. So one version of you app would be client, and the other invoice.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Sebastian, unfortunately it's not duplicated post.  I intended to create two apps with two different datastore.  Two apps will remain in the same domain but different app names, e.g. app1.mydomain.com and app2.mydomain.com and they are two totally different apps.

Answer (score 1):

You could also run the two different "apps" as different *versions* of the same appid.  Then they share the datastore.  Also, urlfetch.fetch() calls to paths of the same app are treated specially, they are faster and don't require authentication (they count as if they are logged in as admin).

Comment: Thanks for your comment but I don't want to share datastore, I want two separate apps with their own datastore.  Two apps are under same domain like app1.mydomain.com and app2.mydomain.com.  Both apps have authentication to domain and how does app1 rpc app2?

Comment: YOu'll still be using urlfetch. There's no assumption of automatic trust between apps running on the same domain; you should be able to cook something up using a shared secret.

Comment: Thanks Guido, I think that's the only way for now.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will be best served by exposing a REST API for both your applications, so that they can read/write information as needed.

For e.g. If one of your apps is an Invoicing App and the other app needs only read access to Invoices, you can expose an API in the Invoice App for:

- searching invoices by some filter
- providing the Invoice detail, given an Invoice ID

Exposing an API will keep the applications loosely coupled with each other and will allow you to enhance the API as more requirements emerge. In the future, you can even have other clients like a mobile app access the API.

Comment: Is it the new API?  The reason I ask is that without API, I am not able to call another app even though they are within the same Domain.  Assuming these two apps are restricted to domain users only, so I guess API is the only way, right?  But then API is currently in Beta, isn't it?

Comment: I am not referring to the new Endpoints API which will make the task simpler. The Endpoints API if I understand right is still in the Trusted Testers program. My recommendation is to write a simple API yourself that exposes the data that you need. For e.g. something like invoiceapp.appspot.com/invoices/INV-100 will return the Invoice information for Invoice# INV-100 in JSON or XML format. The other application can then consume it.

Comment: Thanks Romin.  However, my question would be, how do I write that? because both apps are restricted to domain so how does one app do RPC on another with authentication in mind? Using OAUTH?  Thanks.