# Is it possible to share datastore entities between projects/apps in google app engine?

Tags: google-app-engine

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Google App Engine - one datastore for different domains and apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/811166/google-app-engine-one-datastore-for-different-domains-and-apps)

Is it possible to share datastore entities between projects/apps in google app engine?

If I have two projects which both update an entity with the same Kind and Identifier will they be able to access the same object?

Would [Name Spaces](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/multitenancy/multitenancy#Using_Namespaces_with_the_Memcache) be accessible across apps in the same account?

Comment: See answers for question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/811166/google-app-engine-one-datastore-for-different-domains-and-apps. You basically need to have two version under the same app_id.

Comment: The versions thing won't work for us but its useful to know for sure that its not supported thanks. The bug link in the answer to the linked question was very useful. If you write this as an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See answers for question [Google App Engine - one datastore for different domains and apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/811166/). You basically need to have two versions under the same app_id.